# JSF beginner , how to get this layout?

Tags: jsf

i'm new on jsf and richfaces . Currently I'm developing my fistr jsf application (billing application) and i need of create the pages for insert orders and bill , the pages should have the following layout

[My Layout](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/immagineifl.png/)

how to get this ?

Comment: Do you know html and css? If not you sure learn them a bit. Because layout usually done using css.

Comment: JSF is a HTML/CSS code generator. First mockup the desired layout using some HTML/CSS and finally simply write JSF code as such that it generates exactly that HTML/CSS. Note that you can just put plain HTML elements in a JSF page (provided that you're using JSF version newer than 1.2).

Answer (score 2):

You still have to use CSS to achieve this layout, it has (almost) nothing to do with JSF. [Here](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/) you can find some nice examples and tutorials.

And for the JSF part, you will have the template page where you will define parts which you want to keep same on each page (like menu and footer) and parts which you want to replace on each page (this is usually the content). You can, for example, follow [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/) tutorial from Mkyong.